# enable scroll on fixed side menu and disable on body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create scrollable side menu that is position fixed on top of my content, but the problem is that even if i have overflow-y: auto on the aside element / side menu nothing happens.
I want to side menu to always take up the full height of the screen no matter how little content inside.

I need to disable the scroll on the rest of the content while scrolling the side menu so i hid the overflow on the body.

```css
article {
  height: 300px;
}

aside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 23%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
aside article {
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <h2></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
        Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
        Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
        Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
        Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
        Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
      </p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <article>
        <h2></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
          Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
        </p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
          Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
        </p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
          Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
        </p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2></h2>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam?
          Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
        </p>
      </article>
    </aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) properties to fix the nav dimensions relative to view port.

Since the problem is solved I am keeping scrollbar on body in the following demo.

```css
article {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

aside {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  
  /* my styles */
  overflow: auto;
  inset: 0 74vw 0 0;
  /* or use following */
  /*
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  */
}

aside article {
  background-color: #ccf;
}

body {
  /* I don't know why you don't want scroll on body */
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}

body>article {
  margin-left: calc(23vw + 0.5rem);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>One</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h2>Three</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h2></h2>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <h2></h2>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
  </p>
</article>
<aside>
  <article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2></h2>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio dicta obcaecati iste culpa amet earum totam? Aliquam, rem deleniti quod blanditiis ad ducimus autem hic aperiam earum nostrum maiores. Temporibus?
    </p>
  </article>
</aside>
```